# import a file into an array, python

Tags: python, extract

i need to import a file into an array. The file is like this

```
2017-12-21T14:49:17.518Z
2017-12-21T14:50:49.723Z
2017-12-21T14:50:54.028Z
2017-12-21T14:50:54.343Z
2017-12-21T14:50:59.084Z
2017-12-21T14:50:59.399Z
2017-12-21T14:51:04.142Z
2017-12-21T14:51:04.457Z
2017-12-21T14:51:09.204Z
2017-12-21T14:51:09.521Z
2017-12-21T14:51:14.261Z
2017-12-21T14:51:14.579Z
2017-12-21T14:51:19.326Z
2017-12-21T14:51:19.635Z
2017-12-21T14:51:24.376Z
2017-12-21T14:51:24.691Z
2017-12-21T14:51:29.435Z
2017-12-21T14:51:29.750Z
2017-12-21T14:51:34.498Z
2017-12-21T14:51:34.813Z
2017-12-21T14:51:39.553Z
2017-12-21T14:51:39.868Z
2017-12-21T14:51:44.612Z
2017-12-21T14:51:44.927Z
2017-12-21T14:51:49.675Z
2017-12-21T14:51:49.990Z
2017-12-21T14:51:54.738Z
2017-12-21T14:51:55.042Z
```

. and i need to import it into a list like this

```
times = [
    '2017-12-21T14:49:17.518Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:49.723Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:54.028Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:54.343Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:59.084Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:50:59.399Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:04.142Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:04.457Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:09.204Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:09.521Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:14.261Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:14.579Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:19.326Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:19.635Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:24.376Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:24.691Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:29.435Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:29.750Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:34.498Z',
    '2017-12-21T14:51:34.813Z'
]
```

Now, i don't know what am doing wrong, i used the code

```
times = []
impo= open('checck.txt','r')
for line in impo.readline():
    times.append(line)
```

but am not getting that, i tried to export it using

```
joinliens = ''.join(times)
open('ext.txt', 'w').write(joinliens)
```

but i couldn't get the list am expacting. in the command line, if i print out, i get soemthing close,but i can't export that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `readlines()` instead of `readline()` - notice ending **s**:

```
for line in impo.readlines():
    times.append(line)
```

Also, when saving/writing out, do this:

```
joinliens = ''.join(times)
with open('ext.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(joinliens)
```

Comment: thanks, i forgot to put 's' i mean readlines, and i kept on getting error, but the saving part is giving me a weird result.  i don't know why. its spilting the result

Comment: @idrisbadmus What do you mean it is "splitting the result"? If it adds an extra empty line - that's because I wrote `'\n'.join(times)` and it should have been like how you did originally because `readlines()` keeps the ending newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['times'])

times = df['times'].tolist()  # output as list

df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['times'])  # output as datetime series
```

Answer (score 0):

```
impo = open('checck.txt', 'r')
    times = [line.strip() for line in impo.readlines()]
```

`for line in impo.readline():` didnt work, because that read **one** line and looped over each *character* in the line.